# access a java class from within groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I have a simple java class:

```
package test;
class Hello {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hi");
  }
}
```

on which I do a

```
javac Hello.java
```

Problem: Now I would like to access this class from a groovy script (access.groovy) ...

```
import test.*
Hello.main(null)
```

but

```
groovy -cp . access.groovy
```

will result in a `MissingPropertyException` . What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your class `Hello` needs to be declared as public to be accessible from other packages. As a dynamic language, Groovy can't identify such errors and ends up looking for a variable named `Hello`.

It's generally a bad idea to use wildcard imports; in this case, using `import test.Hello;` would have given you a better error message.

Comment: It actually seems to work for me as is (Groovy 1.8.2) but +1 for good advice :-)