# gradle determine if on 32bit or 64bit windows system

Tags: java, gradle, 32bit-64bit

I am building a java application and copying some native dll's before packaging with java packager.

How can I determine in gradle if the build system is 32bit or 64bit so that I can copy the right dll files?  At the moment I am manually setting a variable when I remember.

Comment: You create 2 packages.  One for 32 bit and one for 64 bit.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't.  I am not sure why as I haven't looked into it, but when packaging with Javapackager into an .exe (with inno setup) on a 64bit machine  it will install but not run or start on 32bit.  I assume it's to do with the .exe wrapper but am not sure yet.

Comment: @Rob: javapackager, apparently, can only create binaries for the current architecture, so you need to build the binary for 32 bit on a 32 bit architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query system property os.arch to determine your operating system architecture and derive how whether you are on 32bit or 64bit OS

If you are concerned with your JVM  ( you can run 32bit JVM on 64bit system) use 
`sun.arch.data.model` property

Use this task as an example how to access these values

```
task printProps << {
    println System.properties['os.arch']
    println System.properties['sun.arch.data.model']

}
```

More information could be found at the below links:

[How can I tell if I'm running in 64-bit JVM or 32-bit JVM (from within a program)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062020/how-can-i-tell-if-im-running-in-64-bit-jvm-or-32-bit-jvm-from-within-a-program)

[How to find the OS bit type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856694/how-to-find-the-os-bit-type)

Comment: It's not the java I am concerned about, but some dll's that I must package to access sqlserver.  thanks for this answer, I will try it out latter

Comment: It works as advertised.  I was not aware that we could do java like things in gradle.  Thanks

Comment: Gradle is just a bunch of groovy methods / closures with simple executor / scheduler.   Gradle script is groovy code.   Groovy in turn is built up on top of JVM.  So you  can call any Java class from your build script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567378/access-a-java-class-from-within-groovy  you can even call non standard packages and get them downloaded from maven repos https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html